# Cloud Function storage trigger on folder of a particular Bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a scenario for executing a cloud function when something is changed in particular folder of a bucket. While I am deploying a function using cli and passing BUCKET/FOLDERNAME as a trigger, it was giving me an error invalid arguments. Is there any one to give trigger at FOLDER level?

Comment: I've been annoying Google for months about this... I think that is in the Roadmap now (capability to add filter on the trigger), but I don't have any timeline! For now, you have to perform the check manually in your code when your function is called.

Answer (score 4):

You can only specify a bucket name. You cannot specify a folder within the bucket.

A key point to note is that the namespace for buckets is flat. Folders are emulated, they don't actually exist. All objects in a bucket have the bucket as the parent, not a directory.

What you can actually do is implement an if condition inside of your function to only do stuff if the request contains an object with the name of your folder. Keep in mind that by following this approach your function will still be triggered for every object uploaded to your bucket.

Comment: Can you give an example? How do I check that a file was uploaded to a folder called "test", for example?

Comment: @savram - Please post a new question.

Comment: I can't post a new question....how about this. Can you point me in the right direction of how I can delete a file from a certain folder in cloud storage after 1 minute? I think it's best to be an https function(if possible) rather than a storage background function. I want to trigger this manually.

Comment: @savram - your question requires a lot more information. Post a new question. If you cannot because you are blocked for some reason, then wait until you are unblocked.